# Formula autofill manipulation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a large spreadsheet(10,000 rows of formulas) that takes information in from two other sheets. The basic layout that I want is:

```
Row1
=Sheet1!A7
=Sheet2!M7
=Sheet1!A8
=Sheet2!M8
=Sheet1!A9
=Sheet2!M9
...etc.
```

When I try to use to formula auto fill, excel picks up on the wrong pattern and I end up with something like this:

```
=Sheet1!A7
=Sheet2!M7
...
=Sheet1!A11
=Sheet2!M11
=Sheet1!A17
=Sheet2!M17
```

I gave excel 10 cells to base the pattern off of, and have not been able to get it to work. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this (hopefully without VBA)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to avoid the volatile¹ [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) or [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) / [ADDRESS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89) function pairs in favor of the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and a little maths.

In the first two cells use these two formulas.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, 7+ROW(1:1)/2)
=INDEX(Sheet2!M:M, 7+ROW(1:1)/2)
```

Select the two cells and drag the Fill Handle down.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: This is pretty neat +1 -- care to explain how it knows to pick row 7 and not 7.5?

Comment: There is no row 7.5. If you throw a mixed number at something expecting a whole number, typically you will get the whole number, possibly averaged up depending upon the situation. I **could** have forced integer only numbers with `INT(ROW(1:1)/2)` but Excel has the overhead to correct for things like that so if you are going to pay for a powerful computer that handles Excel's error control overhead, why not use it?

Comment: Cool, wasn't aware that the default would be the whole number -- I guess I am so accustomed to rounding that I was assuming it would go 7.5 --> 8. Do you know of any documentation that supports this and/or blog posts? I'm not doubting your logic/response, but want to read more up on this behavior.

Comment: I'm sure it is blogged or defined somewhere but I would not know off hand. I would recommend submitting a question on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com) to get the most informed answer(s).

Comment: Answered my question, and taught me something about Volatile functions! Also to anyone in the future, it is important to actually select the first two cells and drag down, or your formula's will get messed up!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple *VBA* macro that sets up your links.  Use it until a non-*VBA* solution is presented:

```
Sub propagator()
   Dim i As Long, k As Long
   k = 1

   For i = 7 To 99
      Cells(k, 1).Formula = "=Sheet1!A" & i
      k = k + 1
      Cells(k, 1).Formula = "=Sheet2!M" & i
      k = k + 1
   Next i
End Sub
```

Just select the destination worksheet and run the macro.

Adjust the **99** to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without VBA with some `=INDIRECT` trickery -- the following is located in "Sheet3":

[image: Excel Screenshot]

You can type out `Sheet1!A` and `Sheet2!M` in cells `A1` and `A2` respectively and fill down. Then, type a `7` in `B1` and the formula in `B2` -- again fill down. This first formula is effectively incrementing the count by two. Finally, you can type the formula in `C1` and fill down.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `INDIRECT` function to build this, and you can make the pattern work based on your current row number. Assuming your first cell is in Row 2:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & 7+(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)-1))`

`=INDIRECT("Sheet2!M" & 7+(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/2,0)-1))`

`ROW()` returns the current row, which is then divided by 2 (since you only increase one row reference for every two cells), and then subtracted 1 (since we want the first adjustment to be 0).

Answer (score 1):

Try in row 2:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & 7 +QUOTIENT(ROW()-2,2))
```

And in row 3:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!M" & 7 +QUOTIENT(ROW()-2,2))
```

Highlight both and copy down.